# Insert into mysql with preparedstatement not working

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to insert data into my mysql table using java, but I really can't.
I'm using PreparedStatement class to do my insertion and it seems like the '?' is not beeing changed by my variable or something like that.

So follow my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class db{
    static String driverJDBC = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database";
    static String user = "root";
    static String senha = "root";

    public static void InsereVin(db banco,String vin){
        Connection conexao = null;
        Connection con = conexao;
        
        //String instrucaoSQL = "insert into authentication (senha) values (\"senhaMaster\");";
        String instrucaoSQL = "INSERT INTO authentication(senha) VALUES(?);";

        try{
            System.out.println("Carregando o driver jdbc...");
            Class.forName(driverJDBC);
            System.out.println("Driver carregado com sucesso");

            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,senha);
            
            PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conexao.prepareStatement(instrucaoSQL);
            preparedStmt.setString(1, vin);
            /*preparedStmt.setInt       (2, contador);
            preparedStmt.setDate      (3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(date));
            preparedStmt.setTime      (4, java.sql.Time.valueOf(time));
            preparedStmt.setString    (5, impressao);
            */
            System.out.println("Inserindo ...");
            
            preparedStmt.execute(instrucaoSQL);
            System.out.println("Inserido com sucesso");
            preparedStmt.close();
            conexao.close();
            
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Erro");
            e.printStackTrace();    
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        db banco = new db();
        InsereVin(banco,"12345678912345678");
    }
    
}
```

and the error I'm getting:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 1
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
        at db.InsereVin(db.java:39)
        at db.main(db.java:53)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:419)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:192)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

I really can't understand what is going wrong with my code and I'll be very thankfull if someone could help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is causing the error:

```java
preparedStmt.execute(instrucaoSQL);
```

Instead of calling `PreparedStatement#execute`, you are actually calling a method that `PreparedStatement` inherits from `Statement`. See the javadoc for the method you are calling [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute-java.lang.String-). See the javadoc for the method you want to call [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute--).

Upon reading the documentation, it should become clear to you that you need to change `preparedStmt.execute(instrucaoSQL);` to `preparedStmt.execute();` in your code.

Comment: Ok, you right that works really well, thank you